# Should I cache blob content to local HD?

Tags: azure-storage

Suppose I have files in blob storage, and these files are constantly used by my web application hosted in Windows Azure.

Should I perform some sort of caching of these blobs, like downloading them to my app's local hard-drive?

**Update:** I was requested to provide a case to make it clear why I want to cache content, so here it goes: imagine I have an e-commerce web-site and my product images are all high-resolution. Sometimes, though, I would like to serve them as thumbnails (eg. for product listings), and one possible solution for that is to use an HTTP handler to resize the images on demand. I know I could use output-cache so that the image just needs to be resized once, but for the sake of this example, let us just consider I would process the image every time it was requested. I imagine it would be faster to have the contents cached locally. In this case, would it be better to cache it on the HD or to use local-storage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You sure can do it locally if you wish to load images faster with different size and I think downloading images at startup task and unzipping them would be a better approach. The Local Storage will also be in same VM as were you consider HD. You have ability to use local Storage by setting it with your Azure application or you can just use a drive however Local Storage is preferred as you can get part programmatically within your ASP.NET code instead of using a physical folder at C drive.

Comment: You asked "would it be better to cache it on the HD or to use local-storage," but local storage *is* the hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to start answering your question, yes accessing a static content from Role specific local storage would be faster compare to accessing it from Azure blob storage due to network latency even when both compute and blob are in same data center.

There could be a solution in which you can download X amount of blobs from Azure storage during startup task (or a background task) in Role specific Local Storage and reference these static content via local storage however the real question is for what reason you want to cache the content from Azure blob storage? Is it for faster access or for reliability? If reason is to have static content accessible almost immediately then I could think of having it cached at local storage.

There are pros and cons of each approach however if you can provide the specific why would you want to do that, you may get much better to the point response.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a local resource? It gives you a path to a folder on the HD, and you can get a lot of space. You can even keep it around between restarts.

Another option is Azure Cloud Drive. It's fast, and would allow you to share the cache among instances (but only can write at once).

Erick